# Is it okay to unplug every wire from my xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

Is it okay to unplug everything from my xbox 360? Will it hurt anything?

Answer (score 2):

While your console is turned on, you may safely unplug all cables ***except*** for the power cable. Removing the power cable while the console is turned on can cause all sorts of damage; from the DVD getting scratched or drives getting damaged, to savegame corruption.

Never unplug the power while a console/PC is on, unless you're absolutely certain there's no other alternative. If your console/PC no longer reacts, it is safer to hold the power button until the device forcefully shuts down, although not particularly recommended either.

---

Unplugging other cables will have other consequences, though none are dangerous to the console:

- **Controller**: When the controller is unplugged, it either stops working if it's a wired controller or a wireless one whose batteries no longer work, or it stops charging if it's a wireless controller.
- **Audio/Video**: You can no longer hear sounds or see images from your TV or speakers.
- **Ethernet cable or USB WiFi adapter**: Your console can no longer connect to the internet.
- **Kinect**: You can no longer use Kinect.

Naturally, those consequences only last as long as their respective cables are unplugged; plug those back in, and the functionality returns.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it off first. After it's completely shut down, you can remove as many cables as you please.

Comment: Though I would suggest keeping the wires in the console in place